# Number of possible numebers I can collect with given k tokens

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a array of numbers, my task is to visit the numbers in the array in sequence and collect the numbers so the sum is less or equal to a given number `k`.

```
Example1:

arr[] = {1,3,6,2,4}

k = 7

Output:
6 

Explanation:

one possible navigation is:

cost to move from 0 to 1 is |1-3| = 2, remaining tokens i have is 7-2 = 5.
cost to move from 1 to 2 is |3-6| = 3, remaining tokens i have is 5-3 = 2.
cost to move from 2 to 4 is |6-4| = 2, remaining tokens i have is 2-2 = 0.

The other possibilities are [0,1,3,4], [0,1,4], [0,2,4], [0,3,4], [0,4]

So total 6 possibilities.
```

I was asked this question during an interview last week. But I was not able to understand what is the best approach to solve this task.

Also it was mentioned that the number of elements in array can be large so return the result in modulo (10 power 9 + 7). I did not understand what this means.

**Update:**

Tried the solution based on @btilly answer, but got stuck on how to implement this.

```
static int process(int[] arr, int k) {
    // Create old_map for first entry.
    Map<Tuple, Integer> old_map = new HashMap<>();

    // for each value in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // create empty new_map
        Map<Tuple, Integer> new_map = new HashMap<>();
        // for each key, count in old_map
        for (Tuple key : old_map.keySet()) {
            int count = old_map.get(key);
            // add ways to skip this value to new_map
            // add ways to include this value to new_map
        }
        old_map = new_map;
    }

    int answer = 0;
    // for each key, count in old_map
    for (Tuple key : old_map.keySet()) {
        int count = old_map.get(key);
        // if key has 0 tokens add count to answer
        if (key.tokens == 0) {
            answer += count;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}


class Tuple {
    int last_value, sum, tokens;

    public Tuple(int last_value, int sum, int tokens) {
        this.last_value = last_value;
        this.last_value = sum;
        this.last_value = tokens;
    }
}
```

What code should I implement for below comments, I am stuck at this point.

```
// add ways to skip this value to new_map
// add ways to include this value to new_map
```

Also am I following correctly based on the answer mentioned by `btilly`?
Is this the right approach

Comment: First you need to clarify in your question that sum of differences between the elements selected is what is need to be considered. Second why is n't `[0,1]` not an answer ? because `|3-1| = 2` is less than `7`. Does the sequence have to end at the end of the list?

Comment: @SomeDude, yes even I had that doubt after coming out of interview, but this is the whole information I had.

Comment: This seems like a dynamic programming problem, where a subproblem is defined by the last index used, and the remaining value of `k`. For example, three of your sequences start with [0,1]. The subproblem at that point is to find sequences starting at index 1 with `k=5`.

Comment: @user3386109, can you please share some pseudo code for that, I will try implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dynamic programming problem.

What you want to do is define a data type that is a tuple of `(last_value, sum, tokens)`.  You will use that as the key to a `Map` specifying how many ways of getting to this combination.

Your code then follows this pattern.

```
Create old_map for first entry.
for each value in the array
    create empty new_map
    for each key, count in old_map
        add ways to skip this value to new_map
        add ways to include this value to new_map
    old_map = new_map
answer = 0
for each key, count in old_map
    if key has 0 tokens
        add count to answer
```

Now the problem is that the size of the counts can be exponential in the size of the array.  You could store that with `BigInteger`.  But the size of the storage is logarithmic in the size of the number, which means that it is `log(exp(O(size of array))) = O(size of array)`.  This quickly gets unwieldy.  So they don't want you to store the count, but `count % (10**9 + 7)`.  Which is a common trick in programming problems to prove that you really have done the calculation asked for.

Comment: can you please see my updated question, I have added the code which I was trying based on your answer. I am stuck at few points, can you please guide me how to proceed with them. Also is my flow correct for remaining comments?